# Creating custom set container which duplicate values are allowed in

Tags: python, function, class, set, containers

I want to create a custom set in python in which duplicate values are allowed in this set but I don't know how to code that in my (add) function.

```
class CloudTag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tags = set()

    def add(self, *tag):
        self.tags = {*tag}
        if len(tag) in self.tags > 1:
            self.tags = {tag}

cloud = CloudTag()
cloud.add("ass", "jhs", 1, 1)
print(cloud.tags)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOxrz.jpg)

Comment: Please be more clear about what you're trying to do. A set, by definition, cannot have multiple values within it. That sounds more like a list.

Comment: How do you expect your custom set to operate in the presence of duplicate tags? Can you give an example of how you would use it?

Comment: A dictionary that maps keys to an integer count would effectively give you exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.